# Upgrade from 18.04 to 19.04 with out updating all softwares

Tags: apt, 18.04, 19.04, do-release-upgrade

Following softwares I don't want to upgrade, but I want to update Ubuntu to 19.04 from 18.04. How can I do it?

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable 
Listing... Done
code/stable 1.36.1-1562627527 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.36.0-1562161087]
libopenjfx-java/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2 all [upgradable from: 8u161-b12-1ubuntu2]
libopenjfx-jni/bionic-updates,bionic-security 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 8u161-b12-1ubuntu2]
openjfx/bionic-updates,bionic-security 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 8u161-b12-1ubuntu2]

$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Comment: Mixing versions from different releases is a Bad Idea for unskilled users. You risk destroying your system, forcing a complete reinstall. We call mixed systems like that "Frankensystems," and we generally don't provide support for the cryptic, mysterious, and unique errors that often ail them. If you need specific versions of applications, consider building an Ubuntu VM customized for that version.

Comment: @user68186 Basically I want to keep using Java 8 (which is still supported by Oracle). Althought the LTS version is JAVA 11. How can I upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 with Java 8. I could downgrade (to Java 8 in Ubuntu 19.04) after upgrading  (to Java 11 in 18.04) Java, but it is a little bit of work and not that straightforward.

Comment: @user68186 Also could you please suggest. What is the recommended way to install Java 8 in Ubuntu that doesn't interfere with Ubuntu upgrade. For example I would like to use software development tools in my latest Ubuntu. But could I keep a separate docker or VM that has Java 8. I am hoping to have less performance penalty while having the benefit that I could use all other tools and data (not present in that docker image or VM).

Answer (score 1):

## You cannot upgrade from 18.04 to 19.04.

Ubuntu does not allow jumping over versions while upgrading (except for LTS to LTS). You have to go from 18.04 to 18.10 and then 18.10 to 19.04.

However Ubuntu 18.10 reached its end of life last week. So you can't upgrade to 18.10. And therefore you cannot upgrade to 19.04.

## LTS to LTS Upgrade

If you want to continue to use some software specific to 18.04 then do not upgrade to newer versions of Ubuntu. 18.04 is LTS, and you will be able to upgrade directly to 20.04 LTS next year in July when 20.04.1 comes out.

Or you can continue with Ubuntu till April 2023, its end of life. In March 2023 you can upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and then immediately upgrade to 22.04 LTS if you want the latest LTS version available then.

## No holding back packages through upgrade to new version of Ubuntu

No. You will get the same message you got now

```
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading
```

when you try to upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.

Ubuntu upgrade process requires that all packages are up-to-date from the current repository before it allows you to upgrade to the next version of Ubuntu.

## About `OpenJDK-8-jdk` and `OpenJDK-11-jdk`

It is my understanding that both can be installed on the same machine at the same time. You can use the following command to switch between the two versions of Java:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This will show you the list of Java versions currently installed and allow you to choose which one to use. Run the same command again and choose a different version if you want to switch.

Hope this helps